# Reason for GC peak splited

Tags: chromatography

I ran GCMS and one of the peak of GC appears:

[image]

The peak shows some tailing, but there seems to be another peak at right-hand end of the signal. I have already checked the MS and confirmed that there is no other compound. What could this be due to?

Comment: Are you overloading the GC column by injecting too much? Try reducing the injection volume and/or increasing the split ratio and see what happens to the peak shape.